# How to use javascript value in href (Laravel)

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, href

Im trying to make simple website using QR Code. I use QR Code scanner from [instascan](https://github.com/schmich/instascan) from github. This line is to show scan result

```
<li v-for="scan in scans" :key="scan.date" :title="scan.content">@{{ scan.content }}</li>
```

How to use that result in href tag like `<a href="/products/show/{{ scan.content }}">@{{ scan.content }}</a>`
The link should be http://example.com/products/show/qrscanresult

Thank you, sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the value like you have done with the other attributes in your question and just concatenate it to the initial part of the url:

```
<a :href="'/products/show/' + scan.content">@{{ scan.content }}</a>
```

Comment: bro, is possible to redirect to that url when the message shown?

Comment: @IkhsannulHijri I don't know what message you're talking about sorry. I would suggest creating a new question as it sounds like it goes out of scope for this one.

Answer (score 0):

assuming {{scan.script}} is the js Variable that changes.

```
<a href="/products/show/<script>{{ scan.content }}</script>">@{{ scan.content }}</a>
```

**Or**

```
<script>var link = '<a href="/products/show/"+{{ scan.content }}></a>Text Goes here</a>'</script>
```

Comment: thank you for your comment. but this works for me <a :href="'/products/show/' + scan.content">@{{ scan.content }}</a> :)